# CS0246 Error while installing IBM Watson SDK for Unity

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, unity3d-editor

I am getting the following errors while trying to use the IBM Watson SDK with Unity.

Assets/unity-sdk-6.0.0/Examples/ExampleNaturalLanguageClassifierV1.cs(43,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NaturalLanguageClassifierService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

(all errors shown in screenshot)

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuqmF.png)

I want to create a 3D AR Avatar that gives info about a person using IBM Watson STT. I have unity-sdk-6.0.0, unity-sdk-core-1.2.4 and I'm using Unity 2021.3.1f1.